# It is possible to use telegram API get a message group chat without using bot?

Tags: go, telegram, mtproto

I have a question about telegram API.

I've read documents on [core.telegram.org](https://core.telegram.org) already.

As per my understanding, the most API is about bot to manage a group channel or publish a message. But my use case is like to use API to get message from any chats for user that auth with my application, Reply chat with user account something like this. It is possible to do with telegram API? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, it is not possible to use the Telegram API to directly retrieve message data from a group chat without using a bot.

The Telegram API requires authentication and the use of a bot token to access chat information and perform actions on behalf of the bot. Bots are specifically designed to interact with users and groups, allowing developers to create automated services and applications within the Telegram platform.

Comment: Thx. This is mean telegram API is suitable to using a bot to manage a group chat more than using to monitor a chat in group or using to publish message right?